# C not reading second getch()

Tags: c, getch

My C program does not let me read the second getch() value. Does anyone know what's wrong with it??

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

struct user{
    char username[30],password[30],confirmpass[30];
};

int main(){
    struct user u[10];
    int i,j,n;
    printf("Enter the number of users: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        printf("Enter the username: ");
        scanf("%s",&u[i].username);
        printf("Enter the password that comprises of alphabets and numerics only and should be 8 characters long: ");
        for(int j=0;i<8;i++){
            u[i].password[j]=getch();
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("Confirm the password: ");
        for(int j=0;i<8;i++){
            u[i].confirmpass[j]=getch();
            printf("*");
        }
        for(int i=0;i<strlen(u[i].password);i++){
            if(strcmp(u[i].password,u[i].confirmpass)==0){
                printf("The passwords don't match");
                exit(0);
            }
        }
        printf("The user details have been successfully registered!!");
        exit(0);
    }
}
```

I have used getch() here to mask the password. I get similar logical errors with gets() as well.[image]

Comment: `gets()` is now deprecated and I am trying to solve your problem will tell you as soon as I find it.

Comment: @youcantseeme `gets` is not deprecated; it has been **removed** from the standard library as of C11. Any implementation still providing it is doing it off-standard if C11 compliance is otherwise strictly enforced.

Comment: Regarding your problem, when you type your username in, pay very close attention to every keystroke you hit whilst doing so, *especially* after what you think it the *last* character in your name. What did you hit immediately after that? Yeah, that's what is being sucked in to that first `getch`

Comment: You can use this to read the username `scanf("%[^\n]%*c", u[i].username);`

Comment: You don't null-terminate the password “strings” so they aren't strings.  Neither `strlen()` nor `strcmp()` is reliable.  You call `exit()` too soon.  You should not use `exit(0)` in a failure path; use `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)`.  You should normally report errors on `stderr`, not `stdout`.

Comment: OT:  when compiling, always enable the warnings, then fix those warnings.  for `gcc`, suggest: `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantiic -std=C11`